# Low performance on postgis query. How to improve it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I am trying to improve performance of my query. From tutorials i read that a good thing is to first run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. After quick check and little help from [this](https://explain.depesz.com/s/i8u0) website , it looks like i got some problems with inside loop, but I don't have idea how to improve it. I've made 3d index on geoms and normal index on id column. In general this query is returning closest 3d distance from each point to wire:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT
    (ST_3DDistance(veg.geom_veg3Dgr, cables.geom) - veg.z_veg_gr) falldist,
    ST_3DDistance(veg.geom_veg3D, cables.geom) dist3d,
    ST_3DClosestPoint(cables.geom, veg.geom_veg3D) closeST_pt,
    ST_Distance(veg.geom_veg2D, cables.geom) dist2d,
FROM (
    SELECT p.ID AS vegId,
    (
        SELECT wire.id
        FROM wire_voltage_temp AS wire
        WHERE ST_Dwithin(p.geom_veg2D, wire.geom, 70)
        ORDER BY ST_3DDistance(wire.geom, p.geom_veg3D) ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS g2
    FROM veg_span_temp AS p
    OFFSET 0
) AS q
JOIN veg_span_temp AS veg
    ON q.vegId = veg.id
JOIN wire_voltage_temp AS cables
    ON q.g2 = cables.id;
```

Comment: Please show the result of EXPLAIN. With and without the `OFFSET 0` trick.

Comment: And why do you need 500k rows all at the same time?

Comment: That's the link for explain without offset 0:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/vkxn 
And that's with offset 0:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/wdYs

   I got 71 mln records, I am spitting it to 500 k chunks and run query on every single chunk.

Comment: It seems to work better without offset 0 though I'm not sure as buffers may have changed.

Comment: Can you please explain nme what's offset 0 is actually doing? And what buffers means in explain? :)

Comment: `OFFSET 0` is an old trick to force the planner to fence the subquery, that is  prevent it from being flattened. You shouldn't use it unless you know what you're doing. You can find all you want to know about buffers in the manual.